# How to assign multiple IPs to Microsoft Azure VM?

Tags: azure

I need two SSL certificates, thus I need to assign two IPs to my Microsoft Azure VM. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to run off the same IP using SNI which allows multiple SSL binding to a single IP.  This [article](http://www.vic.ms/microsoft/windows-azure/multiples-ssl-certificates-on-windows-azure-cloud-services/) goes through the actions required for a Cloud Service, but the same principals apply.

Comment: I was aware of SNI, but resistant to use it due to legacy browser support. Though it looks like only Windows XP users running on IE will be affected. I think I can live with that. If default SSL binding is set up, only downside is legacy browsers showing SSL warning on one of the two domain names.

Comment: From my initial testing I found it used the default SSL quite gracefully (certainly on IE6 in XP), although I've yet to push the SNI up to production fully tested.  HTH.